# ES6 - Loop through objects of objects and mutate the object with additional properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I’m trying to loop through the counties object of object and add two new properties(nameCombined & codeCombined) to the existing Keys (Bucks and Montgomery)

I got up till here. But not able to mutate :(

```
Object.entries(object1).forEach((item, key) => item.map(item => console.log('item', item)));
```

Here is the Data:

```
const counties = {
  "Bucks": {
        "countyCode": "42017",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    },
    "Montgomery": {
        "countyCode": "42091",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    }
};
```

Expected Result:

```
"Bucks": {
        "countyCode": "42017",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA”,
    nameCombined: “Bucks (PA)", // basically this the end result of => key + " (" + counties[key].stateCode + ")"
        codeCombined: “42017 PA Bucks”// basically this the end result of =>  counties[key].countyCode + " " + counties[key].stateCode + " " + key

    },
    "Montgomery": {
        "countyCode": "42091",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA”,
    nameCombined: “Montgomery (PA)", // basically this the end result of => key + " (" + counties[key].stateCode + ")"
        codeCombined: “42091 PA Montgomery”// basically this the end result of =>  counties[key].countyCode + " " + counties[key].stateCode + " " + key
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right path with `entries` and `forEach`, but if you want to mutate the original object then `map` isn't what you want-- that is intended to both iterate over items in an array and, critically, return a new array.  Instead, you can simply mutate the original in the body of your `forEach`, like so:

```js
const counties = {
  "Bucks": {
        "countyCode": "42017",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    },
    "Montgomery": {
        "countyCode": "42091",
        "globalStateCode": "PA",
        "stateCode": "PA"
    }
};

Object.entries(counties).forEach(([countyName, county]) => {
  county.nameCombined = `${county.countyCode} (${county.stateCode})`;
  county.codeCombined = `${county.countyCode} ${county.stateCode} ${countyName}`;
});

console.log(counties);
```

Note you could get a bit cuter with destructuring to cut down on all of the `county.someProperty` above.  Also worth noting-- be careful if you're mutating objects-- if you do it too liberally it can cause a real debugging nightmare.

**EDIT**

In response to the question in comments:

> Why is `[countyName, county]` is in array notation?

The output of [Object.entries(someObject)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will be an array of arrays, in which the inner arrays consist of a property/key of the original object and the value.  This is perhaps better understood via example:

```js
const lumberjanes = {
   scientist: 'Jo',
   strategist: 'Mal',
   enforcer: 'April',
   archer: 'Molly',
   wildcard: 'Ripley',
};

console.log(Object.entries(lumberjanes));

/*
Logs:
[
  ['scientist', 'Jo'],
  ['strategist', 'Mal'],
  ...etc
]
*/
```

When we loop over that output, if we just write it as

```js
Object.entries(lumberjanes)
    .forEach(entry => `Name: ${entry[1]}; Role: ${entry[0]}`);
```

we have to access the values by their index, which isn't very readable at a glance.  If instead we can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to separate that parameter into named variables before we access them in the function body, like so:

```js
Object.entries(lumberjanes)
    .forEach(([name, entry]) => `Name: ${name}; Role: ${entry}`);
```

Comment: why is [countyName, county] is in array notation. pardon my silly question. Just trying to understand